# Why must VBOs be "broken in?"

Tags: java, lwjgl, vbo

If I create a VBO in LWJGL of, say, 128,000 vertices, and push it to the graphics card, there's a considerable delay. This delay lasts for about 11 to 12 milliseconds. The same thing happens the second and third time I push the (slightly changed) array. However, after that, the length of the delay sharply drops to between 1 and 3 milliseconds. Why exactly does this happen? I can't seem to think of a plausible reason for this phenomenon; perhaps someone could shed some light onto the situation?

Comment: To give you an accurate answer, it would be informative to know exactly how you are creating and updating the buffer as well as how you are timing it.

Comment: I feel as though it would be easiest to show you the class responsible solely for handling and updating the buffer. I should mention that when I measure the delay, I do so after the initial "chunk" arrays have been created, and so the code is doing effectively the same thing every time I check it. http://bit.ly/158Jt2z

Comment: I've got 2 suspicions. Number1 is that the GPU driver may ignores the GL_STATIC_DRAW when it realizes that you update the buffer a lot. You can test if this is the case by measuring if this delay comes from either `glBufferData` `glDrawArrays`. If neither of those is the case then it has nothing to do with OpenGL and your actual time-waste is your heavy copying and data processing in Java. The reason it speeds up after a while there is that the Hotspot Compiler recognized this section as repeating and compiled it to machine code at runtime to speed it up.

Comment: A third possibility is that the driver may be multi-buffering for you behind the scenes; the first, second and third times it's allocating new buffer memory, subsequent times it's recycling previously allocated memory.

Comment: @PeterT I'll run a test to see where exactly the delay occurs. As for the second possibility you mentioned, that's not possible, as all array creation and modification are done in a separate thread from the on responsible for drawing.